# Does the correlation between the measurement noise influence the result of the LS?

Tags: linear-algebra, estimation, least-squares, parameter-estimation

Consider a linear measurement process with some noise:
$$y=Hx+v$$
with 
$$v \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$$
the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is not a diagonal matrix. As we know, using LS, the $\hat{x}$ is 
$$\hat{x} = (H^T H)^{-1} H^T y$$
Does it change when $\Sigma$ is not a diagonal matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I eventually realize it is a simple question. Here is the answer of mine.

first, for a semi-definite matrix $\Sigma$, we can find $\Lambda$ so that
$$\Sigma = \Lambda \Lambda^T$$

Then, we have 
$$\Lambda^{-1} v ∼ \mathcal{N}(0,I) $$

So, we can apply the conventional LS to modified measurement process:
$$ \Lambda^{-1}y =\Lambda^{-1}Hx+\Lambda^{-1}v$$
then 
$$\hat{x} = ((\Lambda^{-1}H)^T \Lambda^{-1}H)^{-1} (\Lambda^{-1}H)^T \Lambda^{-1} y$$
$$\hat{x} = (H^T \Sigma ^{-1}H)^{-1} H^T \Sigma ^{-1} y$$